# Subtraction of matrices with different dimensions based on the index

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array where each element of the array is an array of points given by pairs of coordinates.

For example:

```
x = array([[[1, 2],
   [3, 4]],
   [[22,  4],
   [ 9, 10]]])
```

On the other hand I have a list whose length matches the first dimension of the previous matrix where each element is a pair of coordinates.

For example:

```
y = [[1,2],[7,8]]
```

I would like to be able to efficiently subtract both, so that:

```
r = array([[[0, 0],
       [2, 2]],
       [[15,  -4],
       [ 2, 2]]])
```

Of course with a loop I know I could do it easily, but I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand the nature of object dtype arrays.  Such arrays have pointers just like lists.  There isn't numpy magic that avoids python level loops.

Comment: Do you consider list comprehension as a loop? If not, why not `z = [a - b for a, b in zip(x, y)]`? I doubt there are simpler ways to do this. Anyway, storing np-arrays in a np-array seems a little strange to me in the first place.

Comment: If you have Numpy arrays of arrays probably means that there is something wrong in your code: for instance the two inner arrays could be hoisted out of the x array. You can use a chunck or split operator to do this.

Comment: @j1-lee  I just modified the question to remove the question about the objects

Comment: Revert that edit.  Those are still object dtype arrays!

Comment: @hpaulj sorry, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original example has a 2 element array:

```
In [294]: x = np.array([np.array([[1, 2],
     ...:    [3, 4]]),
     ...:    np.array([[22,  4],
     ...:    [ 9, 10],
     ...:    [ 3,  2]])], dtype=object)
     ...: 
In [295]: x.shape
Out[295]: (2,)
In [296]: y = [[1,2],[7,8]]
In [297]: len(y)
Out[297]: 2
In [298]: [i-j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
Out[298]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [2, 2]]),
 array([[15, -4],
        [ 2,  2],
        [-4, -6]])]
```

That object dtype array is, for most practical purposes, a list of arrays.

### array of lists

```
In [301]: x = np.array([[[1, 2],
     ...:    [3, 4]],
     ...:    [[22,  4],
     ...:    [ 9, 10],
     ...:    [ 3,  2]]], dtype=object)
In [302]: x
Out[302]: 
array([list([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), list([[22, 4], [9, 10], [3, 2]])],
      dtype=object)
```

We can't do the above comprehension because the inner lists don't implement subtraction.

### 3d array

If the inner lists were the same dimension, we would get a 3d array:

```
In [303]: x = np.array([[[1, 2],
     ...:    [3, 4]],
     ...:    [[22,  4],
     ...:    [ 9, 10],
     ...:    ]])
In [304]: x
Out[304]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[22,  4],
        [ 9, 10]]])
In [305]: x.shape
Out[305]: (2, 2, 2)
```

Now we can use array subtraction:

```
In [306]: x-np.array(y)
Out[306]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [-4, -4]],

       [[21,  2],
        [ 2,  2]]])
```

though I think you want this broadcasting of a 2d array with the 3d `x`:

```
In [307]: x-np.array(y)[:,None,:]
Out[307]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 2,  2]],

       [[15, -4],
        [ 2,  2]]])
```

### Object array subtraction

If `y` is changed to (2,) object array itself, then we can do a direct subtraction.  This is because, `numpy` delegates that action to the elements, a kind of implicit list comprehension:

```
In [318]: Y = np.empty(2,object); Y[:]=y
In [319]: Y
Out[319]: array([list([1, 2]), list([7, 8])], dtype=object)
In [320]: x-Y
Out[320]: 
array([array([[0, 0],
              [2, 2]]), array([[15, -4],
                               [ 2,  2],
                               [-4, -6]])], dtype=object)
```

This doesn't have a significant time savings compared to the list comprehension:

```
In [321]: timeit x-Y
14.8 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [322]: timeit [i-j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
17.2 µs ± 59.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

or if I make it a pure list iteration:

```
In [324]: %%timeit X=x.tolist()
     ...: [i-j for i,j in zip(X,y)]
14.4 µs ± 93.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

(Iteration over arrays slower than over lists, though the difference with object dtype isn't large.)

Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss. Operators usually work, because they can delegate to corresponding operators of the elements.  But math functions don't usually work, because few objects have methods like `.exp` or `.sin`.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving such a clear answer, it is exactly what I needed.